# Javascript RegExp match & Multiple backreferences

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, match

I'm having trouble trying to use multiple back references in a javascript match so far I've got: -

```
function newIlluminate() {
  var string = "the time is a quarter to two";
  var param = "time";

   var re = new RegExp("(" + param + ")", "i");

    var test = new RegExp("(time)(quarter)(the)", "i");

  var matches = string.match(test);

  $("#debug").text(matches[1]);

}

newIlluminate();
```

**#Debug** when matching the Regex 're' prints 'time' which is the value of *param*.

I've seen match examples where multiple back references are used by wrapping the match in parenthesis however my match for (time)(quarter)... is returning null.

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your regex `test` simply doesn't match the `string` (as it does not contain the substring `timequarterthe`). Do you want [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Ideally I want to loop through the matches in the string and wrap each in a span. So I would expect matches[1] = time, matches[2] = quarter etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is literally looking for `timequarterthe` and splitting the match (if it finds one) into the three backreferences.

I think you mean this:

```
var test = /time|quarter|the/ig;
```

Comment: That's because it's the first match. `g` changes the behaviour so that it returns all matches in the order they are found.

Comment: Yeah i figured that out seconds after my comment, had my head in this too long going nowhere thanks both! marked as answer because it was first :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `test` simply doesn't match the `string` (as it does not contain the substring `timequarterthe`). I guess you want [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
var test = /time|quarter|the/ig; // does not even need a capturing group
var matches = string.match(test);

$("#debug").text(matches!=null ? matches.join(", ") : "did not match");
```